# WP userControl Property is not recognized or is not accessible

Tags: windows-phone-8, properties, user-controls

I have a usercontrol and within it I declared a property P, when  I use this userControl in a Page and I try to set P I have this error: is not recognized or is not accessible.
how can I solve this problem, thx

Comment: P should be a dependency property not a simple property.

Comment: Go in your xaml.cs and write propdp and hit TAB twice to create a dependency property.

Comment: I have another issue, when I bind the DP P in another page the Setter is not fired, any idea??